# Printing a Python Array

Tags: python

I have the array below that represent a matrix of 20 cols x 10 rows.

What I am trying to do is to get the value located on the third position after I provide the Column and Row Values. For example if I type in the values 3 and 0, I expect to get 183 as answer. I used the print command as follows `print(matrix[3][0][I don't know])` either I get out of range or the undesirable results.
I also organized the data as `matrix[[[0],[0],[180]], [[1],[0],[181]], [[2],[0],[182]],...` without too much success.

I have the matrix data on a csv file, so I can formatted accordingly if the problem is the way I am presenting the data.
Can soomeone, please, take a look to this code and direct me?   Thanks

```
    matrix =[]
    matrix =[
    ['0','0','180'],
    ['1','0','181'],
    ['2','0','182'],
    ['3','0','183'],
    ['4','0','184'],
    ['5','0','185'],
    ['6','0','186'],
    ['7','0','187'],
    ['18','0','198']]
    print(matrix[?][?][value])
```

Comment: For future reference (and easier Googling), this isn't an array, it's a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists). Python's standard library does also have arrays, but usually when people talk about using arrays in Python, they're using a third-party library called NumPy.

Comment: I would highly recommend reading through an introductory course on Python and working through some practice problems/projects from the beginning. If you're posting on here about this, it is clear you haven't made any effort to learn Python yet. I recommend https://automatetheboringstuff.com/ for a complete beginner. It was my introduction into programming a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

your matrix here is  9 * 3

if you want the 185, it's in the 6th row 3rd column, so indexes are 5 and 2 respectively.

matrix[5][2] will print the result, idk why you have a 3rd bracket.

basically to access an element you will do [rowNumber][colNumber] , first brackets will give you whatever is in that position of the big array (a 2 d array is just an array of arrays) so you get an array (1D with 3 element) you then put the index of the element in that 1D array.

Comment: I just corrected the posting.. I put a third bracket because I am very very new to Python. So , it would be print(matrix[5][2])?

Comment: yup, added more details to explain how it works.

Comment: Great news! Please accept the answer if it helped you!